# Layout has been misplaced while view in emulator and mobile

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout, android-relativelayout

I'm implementing a login screen while implementing it in the Android Studio the deigning seems fine, but after building the app to emulator and mobile it seems weird, like the elements are misplaced, stretched and compressed. I'm using the drawable element in different sizes because I want this app to support multiple resolution devices.

**Below image is from XML designing preview**

[image: View from xml design]

**Below image is a screenshot of emulator**

[image: From emulator]

**Below image is from Android device**

[image: from android device]

here is the xml design [link][4]

What I'm doing here wrong, any suggestions would be helpful

```
  [4]: https://pastebin.com/d9MPen7c
```

Comment: The reason is you have not specify the constraint properly.

Comment: Can you suggest me a link or something that I can refer and improve this design

Comment: Try using Constraint Layout.

Comment: I used contraint layout first but the view is worse than this, The element are been out of the view, so I moved to Relative Layout.

Comment: No did not set the constraint properly. that is why it was looking worse.

Comment: `https://pastebin.com/ZfeZYG0i` here is constraint layout I've been build, what is the wrong I've done, and how to do constraint properly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205640/discussion-between-jaymin-and-allwin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you have not set the constraints properly. That is why it looks worse on the real devices.

**Here is the XML code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_UserName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="User Name"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_UserName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="24dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_UserName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_Password"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="24dp"
            android:text="Password"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_UserName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_Password"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="24dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/iv_google_bt"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_Password" />

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_google_bt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp" 
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/et_Password" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_fb_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp" 
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv_google_bt"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/et_Password" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_getstarted_login"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/constraintLayout">

    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="176dp"
        android:layout_height="172dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login_signup"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Dummy text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_getstarted_login" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notamem"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Dummy text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_signup" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have placed my resources like dimen, String and drawable. So, Please change you resources with mine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample code for your problem. Adjust the given static value like drawable value in this code by using your own drawable resources. Hope i help you in little way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EBEBEB">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_round_view"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >
    </View>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/view"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-45dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/view" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:text="Username/Email" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_UserName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtUsername"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_UserName"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Password" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_Password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgleft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/view"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/view"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:background="@drawable/emoji"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/view" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgright"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/view"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/view"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:background="@drawable/emoji"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/view" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_round"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
        android:text="Get Started"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/view"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNotAMemberYet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
        android:text="Not a member yet"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view" 
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/txtSignUp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSignUp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtNotAMemberYet"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textColor="#00BCD4"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: as you can see i removed some redundant code from your code and avoid as much as possible to set static value in the code so it will become responsive to every size of device. you just set your constraint not properly so that's the reason in other device it's wrong  :)